# Drupal: trimming functionality is not useful if the customer adds empty lines

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Views in Drupal.

I have an issue with the trimming functionality. I've set the trim to 240 characters in order to avoid the content to overlap the next section.

However, if there are spaces, let's say the customer adds 2 empty lines, this doesn't work anymore.

How could I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can set a fixed `height` and set `overflow: hidden` in CSS to prevent the overlap.